# TinyMCE buttons that launch Ajax-generated forms

Tags: tinymce, shortcode

if i follow the tutorials on how to add tinyMCE buttons for shortcodes

( for instance: http://www.garyc40.com/2010/03/how-to-make-shortcodes-user-friendly/ )

if i create a button that launches a form in a thickbox there is always this bit of code to create the launched form:

```
// executes this when the DOM is ready
    jQuery(function(){
        // creates a form to be displayed everytime the button is clicked
        // you should achieve this using AJAX instead of direct html code like this
        var form = jQuery('<div id="kiaAWeber-form"><table id="mygallery-table" class="form-table">\
            <tr>\
                <th><label for="mygallery-columns">Columns</label></th>\
                <td><input type="text" id="mygallery-columns" name="columns" value="3" /><br />\
                <small>specify the number of columns.</small></td>\
            </tr>\

        </table>\
        <p class="submit">\
            <input type="button" id="mygallery-submit" class="button-primary" value="Insert Gallery" name="submit" />\
        </p>\
        </div>');

        var table = form.find('table');
        form.appendTo('body').hide();
```

but i am curious about this  part in particular :

**// you should achieve this using AJAX instead of direct html code like this**

i've seen this on other tutorials, and in other plugins.... but all i've seen continue to do it this hard-coded way.  does anyone have any insight into how to do this via ajax?

i'd like to popular a select drop-down with values from get_options().. which i cannot do in jquery/java and the js file can't process the php either, so i figured ajax is the solution i'm just not sure how to start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by using [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

so, instead of that big form variable:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'admin-ajax.php',
  data: { action: 'get_my_form' },
  success: function(response){
    var table = $(response).find('table'); // you don't seem to use this "table" var
    $(response).appendTo('body').hide();
    // ...
  }
});
```

Now, the php:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_get_my_form',  'get_my_form');

function get_my_form(){
  // build your form here and echo it to the screen
  exit;
}
```

Comment: almost- actually looks like i am doing almost exactly what you were doing in this question: wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14974/… you selected an answer, but i'm not sure how that worked since it looks like you'd be parsing php in a js file.  what did you end up using for tb_show() ?

Comment: Your not parsing PHP, but HTML. You're just calling a page that's being generated with PHP, using javascript, ie. `admin-ajax.php?action=get_my_form`, and the output of that page is sent to you as `response` in the success() function. My case was similar, the only difference is that my javascript code was inline, so I used PHP to generate the URL. Are you using the thickbox script?

Comment: tb_show( 'Insert AWeber Form', ajaxurl + '?action=get_my_form' ); is the difference. tb_show() wasn't working for me w/ the dynamically added divs. in your other question i was thrown off by the add_query_arg which is def php, but you've explained that since your script is inline. i don't think you need the $.ajax call in that case do you?

Comment: If you're using thickbox, no. They do pretty much the same thing.